# I am not if i am disposing the SPSite and SPweb properly

Tags: sharepoint

i having trouble with diposing the spweb and spsite. i think i followed the instructions correctly for disposing the objects but my webpart is still slow. My goal is to get the discussion board list and i did that part correctly but my webpart takes forever to load. Please provide any suggestions. Does anything else needs to be disposed or should i use try and finally block.

I tried to use the using() statement still the site is slow.

```
       using(SPSite site=new SPSite("https://example.com/discussion/posts"))
    {
         using(SPWeb web=site.OpenWeb())
         {
        SPListCollection sPListCollection = web.Lists;    
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> newData = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            List<string> subject = new List<string>();

            if (sPListCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (SPList list in sPListCollection)
                {


                    if (list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.DiscussionBoard)
                    {

                        SPListItemCollection ListRows = list.Items;
                        SPListItemCollection oldTopics = list.Folders;



                        foreach (SPListItem topic in oldTopics)
                        {



                            if (topic["Subject"] != null)
                            {

                                subject.Add(topic["Subject"];


                            }

                            else
                            {
                                subject.Add("");

                            }        

                        }
                    }

                }
                newData.Add("Subject", subject); 
            }
         }
 return newData;

    }
         }
```

The webpart is still slow. I think i used the using statement incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

there can be many reasons why your webpart is slow.
I see that you are retrieving all the list items in all lists; this is very intensive.
also i see syntax errors in your code

subject.Add(topic["Subject"]; //missing ')'